# Assigning NAs to rows with conditional statement in r

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, conditional-statements, na

I'm trying to assign NAs to the first two rows of each event, with the following conditional statement:
If the first day of each event has a value of "variable" = 0, check the day before. If the day before (last day of previous event) has a "variable" > 0, then assign NAs to the first two rows of the event having "variable" = 0 on the first day. If the day before has a "variable" = 0, do nothing.

Here is an example:

```
day <- c(1:16)
event<- c(1,1,2,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,6,6,6,7,7,7)
variable<- c(0,0,5,0,0,0,10,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0)
A<- data.frame(day, event, variable)
```

```
     day  event  variable
1     1     1        0
2     2     1        0
3     3     2        5
4     4     3        0
5     5     4        0
6     6     4        0
7     7     4       10
8     8     5        0
9     9     5        1
10   10     5        1
11   11     6        0
12   12     6        0
13   13     6        0
14   14     7        0
15   15     7        0
16   16     7        0
```

And how it should look like

```
     day  event  variable
1     1     1        0
2     2     1        0
3     3     2        5
4     4     3       NA
5     5     4        0
6     6     4        0
7     7     4       10
8     8     5       NA
9     9     5       NA
10   10     5        1
11   11     6       NA
12   12     6       NA
13   13     6        0
14   14     7        0
15   15     7        0
16   16     7        0
```

Note: It doesn't matter if event 1 has to be assigned with NAs
I tried to do this with if conditions, but is not working well. Any idea? and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: New example data from OP

```r
library(data.table)
event2<- c(1,2,2,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,5) 
variable2<- c(140, 0, 69, 569, 28, 0,0,0,100,0,0) 
desire_output<- c(140, NA, NA, 569, 28, 0,0,0,100, NA,NA) 
A2<- data.frame(event2, variable2, desire_output) 

setDT(A2)

A2[,first_days_event:=fifelse(.I==min(.I),1,fifelse(.I==min(.I)+1,2,NA_integer_)),by=.(event2)]

A2[,result:={v <- variable2
for (i in 2:.N) {
  if (is.na(first_days_event[i])) {
    v[i] <- variable2[i]
  } else if (first_days_event[i]==1 & variable2[i]==0){
    if (variable2[i-1]>0) {
      v[i] <- NA_integer_
      if (first_days_event[i+1]==2) {
        v[i+1] <- NA_integer_
      }
    }
  }
}
v}]
A2
#>     event2 variable2 desire_output first_days_event result
#>  1:      1       140           140                1    140
#>  2:      2         0            NA                1     NA
#>  3:      2        69            NA                2     NA
#>  4:      3       569           569                1    569
#>  5:      4        28            28                1     28
#>  6:      4         0             0                2      0
#>  7:      4         0             0               NA      0
#>  8:      4         0             0               NA      0
#>  9:      4       100           100               NA    100
#> 10:      5         0            NA                1     NA
#> 11:      5         0            NA                2     NA
```

---

I will use this simple `loop` solution. Just need to create a flag indicating the first tow days of each event.

```r
library(data.table)

day <- c(1:16)
event<- c(1,1,2,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,6,6,6,7,7,7)
variable<- c(0,0,5,0,0,0,10,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0)
A<- data.frame(day, event, variable)

setDT(A)


A[,first_days_event:=fifelse(.I==min(.I),1,fifelse(.I==min(.I)+1,2,NA_integer_)),by=.(event)]

A[,result:={v <- numeric(.N)
  for (i in 2:.N) {
    if (is.na(first_days_event[i])) {
      v[i] <- variable[i]
    } else if (first_days_event[i]==1){
      if (variable[i-1]>0) {
        v[i] <- NA_integer_
        if (first_days_event[i+1]==2) {
          v[i+1] <- NA_integer_
        }
      } else {
        v[i] <- variable[i]
      }
    }
  }
v}]

A
#>     day event variable first_days_event result
#>  1:   1     1        0                1      0
#>  2:   2     1        0                2      0
#>  3:   3     2        5                1      5
#>  4:   4     3        0                1     NA
#>  5:   5     4        0                1      0
#>  6:   6     4        0                2      0
#>  7:   7     4       10               NA     10
#>  8:   8     5        0                1     NA
#>  9:   9     5        1                2     NA
#> 10:  10     5        1               NA      1
#> 11:  11     6        0                1     NA
#> 12:  12     6        0                2     NA
#> 13:  13     6        0               NA      0
#> 14:  14     7        0                1      0
#> 15:  15     7        0                2      0
#> 16:  16     7        0               NA      0
```

Comment: Hey @Frank thanks for your answer. It really worked with that example but is not working with all possible scenarios. Can you take a look at this example:

Comment: event2<- c(1,2,2,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,5)
variable2<- c(140, 0, 69, 569, 28, 0,0,0,100,0,0)
desire_output<- c(140, NA, NA, 569, 28, 0,0,0,100, NA,NA)
A2<- data.frame(event2, variable2, desire_output)

Comment: In which the desire_output is how I expect it to be the solution

Answer (score 1):

Here is a potential `tidyverse` approach.

You can store the last value of a group in a temporary column `last_var` and use `lag` to move to the first row of the following group for comparison.

Note that the default in `lag` will determine if `variable` in `event` 1 is 0 or `NA`.

The final `mutate` will evaluate the row if within the first 2 rows of the group, and check `last_var` to determine if should set to `NA` or leave alone.

**Edit**: For the `ifelse` need to also check if first day's `variable` for the event is 0.

```
library(tidyverse)

A %>%
  group_by(event) %>%
  mutate(last_var = ifelse(row_number() == n(), last(variable), 0)) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  mutate(last_var = lag(last_var, default = 0)) %>%
  group_by(event) %>%
  mutate(variable = ifelse(row_number() <= 2 & first(last_var) > 0 & first(variable) == 0, NA, variable)) %>%
  select(-last_var)
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 16 x 3
# Groups:   event [7]
     day event variable
   <int> <dbl>    <dbl>
 1     1     1        0
 2     2     1        0
 3     3     2        5
 4     4     3       NA
 5     5     4        0
 6     6     4        0
 7     7     4       10
 8     8     5       NA
 9     9     5       NA
10    10     5        1
11    11     6       NA
12    12     6       NA
13    13     6        0
14    14     7        0
15    15     7        0
16    16     7        0
```

With the second data frame included in the comments:

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 11 x 3
# Groups:   event [5]
   event variable desire_output
   <dbl>    <dbl>         <dbl>
 1     1      140           140
 2     2       NA            NA
 3     2       NA            NA
 4     3      569           569
 5     4       28            28
 6     4        0             0
 7     4        0             0
 8     4        0             0
 9     4      100           100
10     5       NA            NA
11     5       NA            NA
```

Comment: Hey @Ben, thanks for your answer. It really worked with that example but is not working in all possible scenarios. Can you please take a look at this example a tried to run it with the same idea of the problem.
Here is the example:
event2<- c(1,2,2,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,5)
variable2<- c(140, 0, 69, 569, 28, 0,0,0,100,0,0)
desire_output<- c(140, NA, NA, 569, 28, 0,0,0,100, NA,NA)
A2<- data.frame(event2, variable2, desire_output)
in which the desire output column is how I want it to be solve

Comment: @Noel Try changing the mutate to: `mutate(variable = ifelse(row_number() <= 2 & first(last_var) > 0 & first(variable) == 0, NA, variable))` ... I edited the answer above, let me know...